# Tab index of dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a screen that allows users to add & remove rows which they'll use to input their scores. The input rows gets created based on sample type selected & a pre-configured "template" (eg, going by my picture... I select hearts, and "germs, wholebird" & "Pseudomonas, Crubming" gets added as a default), but they can also append or remove rows as they see fit.

I'd like it so that when a user tabs, it'll only tab through the textboxes, and not the dropdown boxes.

[image]

**The code**

Index

```
    @Html.ActionLink("New Row...", "AddRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })
        <div id="overflw" style="height: 260px; width: 885px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black">
            <div id="editorRows">
                @if (Model.Micros != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.Micros)
                    {
                        Html.RenderPartial("MicroRow", item);
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".deleteRow").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash" },
            text: false
        });          
    </script>
```

MicroRow

```
    <div class="editorRow" style="padding-left: 5px">

    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("micros"))
    {  
        ViewData["MicroRow_UniqueID"] = Html.GenerateUniqueID();

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lab_T_ID, new { UniqueID = ViewData["MicroRow_UniqueID"] })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lab_SD_ID, new { UniqueID = ViewData["MicroRow_UniqueID"] })      
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Result)
        <input type="button" class="deleteRow" title="Delete" value="Delete" />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You can use tabindex attribute to achive this. Can you show template for row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest way I can think of is to hijack your **tab** key whenever you are within one of your text boxes. I've put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLm7A/3/) here which might give a general idea as to what I meant.

```
<input type='text' id='n1' data-key='1' />
<input type='text' id='n2' data-key='2' />
<input type='text' id='n5' value = 'Tab skips me'/>
<input type='text' id='n3' data-key='3' />
<input type='text' id='n4' data-key='4' />

$(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which === 9){
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = $(this), 
                myIndex = parseInt(self.data('key'),10),
                nextIndex = myIndex + 1,
                nextElement = $('input[data-key="'+ nextIndex +'"]');
            nextElement.focus();
        }
    });
});​
```

​

## Edit - Using TabIndexes

While the piece of code above works as advertised, you may also want to check out using ***tabindex***. I will admit, this is something that I did not know existed. But after reading through comments, decided this was something that may be more suited to your requirement. I've [**updated a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLm7A/6/) to show how it works. Check it out

```
<input type='text' id='n1' tabindex='1' value="I'm first" />
<input type='text' id='n2' tabindex='3' value="I'm third" />
<input type='text' id='n5' value="I'm last"/>
<input type='text' id='n3' tabindex='2' value="I'm second" />
<input type='text' id='n4' tabindex='4' value="I'm fourth" />
```

Comment: brilliant! i'll take a stab at it. but seems like the way to go. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden feild in the view store the current tab index value.

As you have tagged Jquery here. Add the code for the below in Jquery

Whenever user clicks on add New row then read the tab index hidden feild value and increment it and set it to the newly added textbox

Whenever user clicks on delete decrement the value of index hidden field.